# Kafka Issue - CommitFailedException [it is likely that the consumer was kicked out of the group]

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I'm working on project, which uses Kafka. Getting Below

`org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.CommitFailedException: Offset commit cannot be completed since the consumer is not part of an active group for auto partition assignment; it is likely that the consumer was kicked out of the group. at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.sendOffsetCommitRequest(ConsumerCoordinator.java:1246) at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.commitOffsetsSync(ConsumerCoordinator.java:1105) at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.commitSync(KafkaConsumer.java:1501) at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.commitSync(KafkaConsumer.java:1448) at com.central.aggregation.engine.consumer.RecordProcessorBuilder$Acknowledger.acknowledge(RecordProcessorBuilder.java:112) at com.central.data.streams.commons.kafka.consumer.MessageProcessingTask.lambda$acknowledge$2(MessageProcessingTask.java:352) at org. spring framework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:287) at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:164) at com.central.data.streams.commons.kafka.consumer.MessageProcessingTask.acknowledge(MessageProcessingTask.java:344) at com.central.data.streams.commons.kafka.consumer.RecordProcessor.acknowledgeCompletedTasks(RecordProcessor.java:224) at com.central.data.streams.commons.kafka.consumer.TopicProcessor.acknowledgeCompletedTasks(TopicProcessor.java:520) at com.central.data.streams.commons.kafka.consumer.TopicProcessor.processTasks(TopicProcessor.java:368) at com.central.data.streams.commons.kafka.consumer.TopicProcessor.run(TopicProcessor.java:270) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)`

My understanding was, consumer get kicked out because processing is taking more time, but this part is also checked, that processing does not go beyond 2sec.

Kafka Config used :

```
Map<String, Object> properties = new KafkaConsumerConfigsBuilder(GROUP_ID)
        .withConnectionConfigs(kafkaCredsStore)
        .withEnableAutoCommit(false)
        .build();

    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, KafkaAvroDeserializer.class.getName());
    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, KafkaAvroDeserializer.class.getName());
    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, GROUP_ID);
    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);

    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 300000);
    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, 1);

    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, 60000);
    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 20000);

    return new KafkaConsumerFactory<>(topicName, properties);
```

Consumer Code -

```
 @Override
@Timed(name = "timed.RecordProcessor.run", absolute = true)
public void run(MessageProcessingTask<KafkaRecord> task)
{
    List<MessageInfo> messageInfoList = new ArrayList<>();
    Map<String, Long> times = new HashMap<>();

    List<AggregationRecord> aggregationRecords = null;
    final List<CompletionNotification> notifications = new ArrayList<>();

    final Counter counter = this.meterRegistry.counter("counted.RecordProcessor.recordLength");

    List<String> commandAndTargetId = new ArrayList<>();
    Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.createStarted();
    times.put("messageReceiptInstant", Date.from(Instant.now()).getTime());
    log.info("No. of messages picked from kafka broker: {}", task.getProcessableMessageContainers().size());

    for (KafkaMessageContainer<KafkaRecord> messageContainer : task.getProcessableMessageContainers())
    {
        final KafkaRecord kafkaRecord = messageContainer.getMessage();

        log.info("Received kafka record with commandId {}, targetId {}",
            kafkaRecord.getCommandId(), kafkaRecord.getTargetId());

        commandAndTargetId.add(String.join(" : ", kafkaRecord.getCommandId(), kafkaRecord.getTargetId()));
        counter.increment(gsonConfig.gson().toJson(kafkaRecord).length());

        Map<String, Integer> totalCounts = new HashMap<>();
        aggregationRecords = createAggregationRecords(kafkaRecord, totalCounts);

        MessageInfo messageInfo = new MessageInfo();
        messageInfo.setCommandId(kafkaRecord.getCommandId());
        messageInfo.setTargetId(kafkaRecord.getTargetId()); ...
```

I'm not sure where I'm getting wrong, please help me in understanding this issue and suggest what can be done here.

Comment: Hi @Deepack, I see that you deactivated the auto-commit, could you please share your consumer (subscribe/assign, poll and commit) code ?

Comment: Hi @Deepack I see you're using a `KafkaAvroDeserializer` in that case you'll need to provide the consumer with `schema.registry.url` configuration.

Comment: @bbejeck `schema.registry.url` configuration is already provided.